# Dynamic and 100% iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a website with a header and a footer. Let's call it domain.com.

Now on a second domain I have 2 files:

> page1.php with a height of 1500px
>  page2.php with a height of
>   800px

Now do I want to add both pages on my domain.com (not at the same time, but with for example domain.com/1 and domain.com/2) with an iframe that shows the full page content (important: of page1.php and page2.php) and adds it between the header and footer.

The iFrame should be without a scrollbar and should look for a user like there is no iFrame.

How can I make a dynamic iFrame that shows the full page (page1.php or page2.php) but also automaticly sets the sizes depending on the page content (as page1.php is larger than page2.php)?

// EDIT:
I forgot to enter important things. The site I want to add as iFrame is a shop website and so is dynamic. There is no fixed height of the site. So I can't use px in height because that would a) show too less (the rest would be "cut out") or show too much (the rest would be simply white). I hope you understant what I mean.

Comment: If you are doing cross domain iframes and have resolved the cors issue you might find it easier to control your content if you just make ajax calls to the pages you want to bring in, pull the content out of the body, and drop it into a div. You can also bring in any js by searching the head element for the script tags and dropping those in as well.

Comment: Thank you, but ajax is definetly not what I can use here. For this, the site I want to add is too complex.

Comment: I have edited the main post. Please read the edited version.

Comment: Don't do this. You just presented the killer counter argument yourself: _"The site I want to add as iFrame is a shop website"_ Any user willing to enter personal info or even payment data into that kind of phishing-adjacent setup, could only be considered a complete moron. Don't make the internet worse than it is, please and thank you.

Comment: What do you mean? I just add a website with an iFrame in my website. Why is this bad?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) to display content is a bit dated, but if it's what you want to do, take a look at the following demo:

<kbd>[Demo](https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/rdpadV)</kbd>

Basically, you just need to make sure your `scrolling` and `frameborder` attributes are properly turned off:

```
<iframe src="https://xhynk.com/" scrolling="no" frameborder="none"></iframe>
```

and it helps to set your CSS to something like this:

```
iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 400px;
}
```

`display: block` removes any inline margin (usually 4px) from the iframe)

`width: 100vw` will set it to your viewport width (though use `100%` instead if you have a sidebar or parent container that's not as wide as the viewport

and set your `height` to whatever pixel size the content is.

So your **domain.com/1** page will look something like this:

```
<header>Page 1</header>
<iframe src="page1.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="none" style="display: block; width: 100vw; height: 1500px;"></iframe>
<footer>&copy; Jelly</footer>
```

And **domain.com/2** will look something like:

```
<header>Page 2</header>
<iframe src="page2.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="none" style="display: block; width: 100vw; height: 800px;"></iframe>
<footer>&copy; Jelly</footer>
```

You may care to read up on the:[`<iframe> Element Documentation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) for more information.

For dynamic heights you can only do this if your don't have Cross Domain issues to worry about, but you can modify the height of the window after it's loaded:

**Add the `onload` attribute to your iframe**:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="page2.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="none" onload="iframeResize()"></iframe>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function iframeResize() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1');
    iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that's not what I looked for. This is a basic iFrame and that would be easy to do. Please have a look at your example, there you can see that everything under "Projects" or "Hi, I'm Alex: Web Developer" is cut out. I want to prevent that and see 100% of the website but not more nor less. Hopefully you have a solution, thanks! To be more detailed and to understand, the page I want to set into the iFrame is dynamic. Imagine adding Facebook in an iFrame, the size is changing over time and you can't set that in px because it's changing.

Comment: I used `400px` as an example. You mentioned having `1500px` and `800px` heights for your files - I didn't noticed the dynamic portion - updated the answer

Comment: No problem, it was my fault! We are coming closer. Does your answer also work, when the user clicks an element in the iFrame? For example if the iFrame is a shop and the user clicks a category.

Comment: No, you're starting to get into a far too complicated territory, part of why I don't recommend iframes for this type of thing. You're better off adding your header and footer directly to the php files, trying to dynamically resize an iframe perfectly on resize and click events is far beyond reasonable practices

Comment: I would, but the site I iFrame is a partner website and I have no access to it.

Comment: Then the javascript functions wouldn't even work since it's Cross Domain, meaning you can't access the content in it with JavaScript. Your best bet is to do something like this then: https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/rdpadV

Comment: Get the height of your `header` and `footer`, and set the height of the iframe to `calc( 100vh - HeaderHeight - FooterHeight )`